# UpdateReceiver Issue

Tags: android

I have an UpdateReceiver in my app. It has to be triggered whenever my app is updated via playstore.

Problem: 
The UpdateReceiver gets called whenever any app is updated via playstore when it should be called only when my app is updated.

my Package name

package="in.ac.site.portal"

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name="in.ac.site.portal.UpdateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:path="in.ac.site.portal"
                android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

 <service android:name="in.ac.site.portal.UpdateService" />
```

My UpdateService.java

```
public class UpdateService extends IntentService{

public UpdateService() {
    super("UpdateService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(this, 
    DashBoardActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
}
```

Any insight to the problem will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check your app version code with current and old,this will slove I suppose.
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Comment: my app versioning is correct. What i can't find out is why UpdateReceiver gets called when some other app is updated

Comment: Store ur app version in shared preference.. When any other app gets updated your app version remains same.. So do nothing.. but when ur app upgrades version code differs do ur work..Make sense?